# js working in console but not from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I'm calling the below function after the data from an ajax call is returned. It performs the first console.log() which contains the data from the ajax call. But the each() loop iterating through - response, does not console.log anything.

```
primaSaveOrder.prototype = {

     start: function(response){

        console.log(response)

        $j('#primaId').val('');
        $j('#dialog').closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');


        $j.each(response['billing'], function(i, val) {
          console.log(response['billing'][i])
        });
    },
 }
```

I don't think my code is too wrong though because if I manually create a variable in the console equal to the output of - console.log(response) and then run the -

```
  $j.each(response['billing'], function(i, val) {
          console.log(response['billing'][i])
        });
```

it works. What I would prefer to run is `$j('#' + i).val(response['billing'][i])` instead of `console.log(response['billing'][i]`.

This also works if I do it directly in the browser but not in the file. I assume it's related but I can't figure out how to fix it.

this is an example of what i am iterating with some data changed for privacy

```
  {"billing":{"order-billing_address_firstname":"test","order-billing_address_lastname":"test","order-billing_address_street0":"6  test","order-billing_address_street1":"test","order-billing_address_city":"","order-billing_address_country_id":"GB","order-billing_address_region":"","order-billing_address_postcode":"16","order-billing_address_telephone":"","order-billing_address_vat_id":"","order-billing_address_prima_address_code":"0"},"shipping":{"order-shipping_address_firstname":"test","order-shipping_address_lastname":"test","order-shipping_address_street0":"6 test","order-shipping_address_street1":"test","order-shipping_address_city":"","order-shipping_address_country_id":"GB","order-shipping_address_region":"","order-shipping_address_postcode":"16","order-shipping_address_telephone":"","order-shipping_address_vat_id":"","order-shipping_address_prima_address_code":"0"}}
```

Comment: Numeric IDs are HTML5 only. Do they all exist? Is response["billing"] an array?

Comment: i just included the structure of what i am looping through. I just took out the customer data

Comment: Billing is not an array. [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) uses `key, value` for objects and `index, value` for arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the type of response is String. In that case convert the response into json using

```
response = JSON.parse(response);
```

before using response for iteration.

Comment: i get the following error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token o, when i run that

Comment: this actually seems to have worked. I don't know why i got an error the first time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't say, it will help, but there are several things that should be checked for issue root:

1. Check whether the elements exist and they are really unique (since ids are used). `console.log(i, $j('#' + i).size())` may do the trick. I believe that there may be no elements to set values.
2. Use `val` argument directly instead of referencing it through `response['billing'][i]`. Though I don't see how the `response` var may be overridden or hidden, but let's use the value directly since it's passed into callback.

Comment: the elements definitely exist. I also ran your code in case. How exactly do you suggest I use val?

Comment: smth. like `console.log(val)` instead of `console.log(response['billing'][i])` since iteration is on `response['billing']`